# Prove or disprove $a-b < \frac{1}{c}$ given $a>b>0$ and $c>0$ and $\frac{a-b}{ae^{-bc}} < 1$

Tags: calculus, inequality

Let $a, b, c$ be strictly positive numbers that satisfy
$$a > b \quad\quad\quad \text{and}\quad\quad\quad \frac{a-b}{ae^{-bc}} < 1.$$
prove or disprove: 
$$a-b < \frac{1}{c}.$$
I did some tests with Wolfram and all of my attempts so far show that this is indeed true. But I am not sure how to prove this analytically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $d=a-b<a$. Then, 
\begin{align}
\frac{a-b}{ae^{-bc}}<1 &\implies \frac{d}{ae^{-(a-d)c}}<1\implies d<ae^{-(a-d)c}\\&\implies \log d <\log a -(a-d)c\implies c<\frac{\log a-\log d}{a-d}.
\end{align}

Let $f(d)=a-d-d\log a+d\log d$. We have $f(a)=0$, and 
\begin{align}
&f'(d) = -\log a+\log d <0, \text{ since }d<a\\
\implies &a-d-d\log d+d\log d=f(d)>f(a)=0\\
\implies &c<\frac{\log a-\log d}{a-d} < \frac{1}{d}\implies d=a-b <\frac{1}{c}.
\end{align}

Comment: if the given inequality is reversed ($\frac{a-b}{ae^{-bc}} > 1$), does the sign of the last result also reverse ($a - b>\frac{1}{c}$)? I don't think it is true using the method that you used.

Comment: The sign does not reverse. For example, $a=2,b=1$ and $c=3/4$ satisfies $a>b$ and  $\frac{a-b}{ae^{-bc}}>1$, but $a-b\ngtr \frac{1}{c}$